Multiple symbol definitions when using the same template type from different DLLs used in the same project
I have a hard problem with multiple definitions of symbols in a complicated environment I do not completely control.
I apologise in advance for the verbosity of the question... but it's quite complicated.
The situation is the following:

I have a header-only library that, for illustration, we'll call FakeGLM.
I have another library (a DLL) that we'll call Lib1.
I have yet another library (again a DLL) that we'll call Lib2.
Finally, I have another DLL that uses those 3 libraries; let's call it UserDll.

All there is in FakeGLM is the following:
// file vec3.h
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>

namespace fake::glm
{
   template <std::size_t Size, typename T>
   struct vec
   {
      T x;
      T y;
      T z;

      constexpr vec(T a, T b, T c) noexcept
         : x{ a }, y{ b }, z{ c }
      {}
   };

   using dvec3 = vec<3, double>;
}

Lib1 contains the following header:
// lib1.h
#include <FakeGLM/vec3.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#ifdef LIB1DLL
#define Lib1API   __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define Lib1API   __declspec( dllimport )
#endif // LIB1DLL
#else
#define Lib1API
#endif // _WIN32

struct Lib1API V_COORD : public fake::glm::dvec3
{
   constexpr V_COORD(double ax, double ay, double az)
      : fake::glm::dvec3(ax, ay, az)
   {}

   void some_func();
};

and the following source file:
// lib1.cpp
#include "lib1.h"

void V_COORD::some_func()
{
}

void dummy()
{
   V_COORD coord{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
}

Lib2 contains this header:
// lib2.h
#pragma once

#ifdef _WIN32
#ifdef LIB2DLL
#define Lib2API __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define Lib2API __declspec( dllimport )
#endif // LIB2DLL
#else
#define Lib2API
#endif // _WIN32

#include <FakeGLM/vec3.h>

namespace lib2
{
   //! Point class template for n-dimensional points.
   template <std::size_t Size, typename T>
   struct Point : public fake::glm::vec<Size, T>
   {
      constexpr Point(double x, double y, double z) noexcept
         : fake::glm::vec<Size, T>{ x, y, z }
      {}

   };

   extern template struct Point<3, double>;

   using Point3d = Point<3, double>;

} // namespace lib2

and the following source file:
// lib2.cpp
#include "lib2.h"

namespace lib2
{
   template struct Lib2API Point<3, double>;
}

Finally, UserDll - which depends on FakeGLM, Lib1, and Lib2 contains the following code:
// file: color.h
#pragma once

#include <FakeGLM/vec3.h>

#include <Lib1/lib1.h> // NOTE: include lib1 without even using things from it, but it's just to trigger the error

namespace userdll
{

   struct Color : fake::glm::dvec3
   {
      Color(double r, double g, double b);
   };

} // namespace userdll

// file: color.cpp
#include "Color.h"

namespace userdll
{
   Color::Color(double r, double g, double b)
      : fake::glm::dvec3(r, g, b)
   {
   }

} // namespace userdll

// file: testfile.h
#pragma once

namespace userdll
{
   class TestClass
   {
      TestClass();
   };
}

// file: testfile.cpp

#include "Testfile.h"

#include <lib2/lib2.h>

namespace userdll
{
   TestClass::TestClass()
   {
      lib2::Point3d point{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
   };

} // namespace userdll

This code on MSVC 17.8 raises the following linker error:
2>Lib1.lib(Lib1.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl fake::glm::vec<3,double>::vec<3,double>(double,double,double)" (??0?$vec@$02N@glm@fake@@QEAA@NNN@Z) already defined in TestFile.obj
2>[path-to]\UserDll.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

As soon as I remove either #include <Lib1/lib1.h or the line lib2::Point3d point{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 }; the linker is happy and does not complain anymore.
Why does the linker say there are multiple definitions of the constructor of fake::glm::vec?
And how can I solve the problem?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

OK, I have expand the example to make Lib1 export something as the problem happens anyway

I don't know what is exactly going on but re-exporting symbols from lower level libraries may is not a good/maintainable idea. So if lib2 has a Point type don't derive it from something from another libarary. E.g. make a lib2::Point a pimpl class that forwards to an implementation class that can derive/implement whatever it wants. At library boundaries only provide types you can control 100% or are build in types or standard library types (as long as C++ promises ABI compatibility)

how are you exporting symbols from these dlls? I see no dllexport/dllimport?

@AlanBirtles FakeGLM is a header-only lib, no need to export anything.
Lib1 is exporting the class V_COORD by using the macro Lib1API which does the dllexport/dllimport thing.
Lib2 explicitly instantiate the Point template and when doing so it exports it using the macro Lib2API.
UserDll is not (currently) exporting anything.

@PepijnKramer, FYI if I make the Point template class have a data member of type fake::glm::vec rather than inheriting, I still have the multiple symbols definitions.
On the other hand, if I make Point a concrete type, inheriting from fake::glm::dvec3, the linker does not complain.
Using the pimpl idiom in this case is not an option as it involves heap allocations but for the framework I'm working on, performance is a must.
